# Getting ElasticSearch Oracle SQL River Working

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, elasticsearch

I am new to ElasticSearch and am trying to set up an instance on my local machine that will connect to an Oracle SQL database on another server. Currently, I'm using ES 1.5.2 and have the plugin ojdbc6.jar downloaded. I'm also using a Windows machine.

I can open the elasticsearch.bat file and successfully start a Test_Node, but I'm having trouble getting the moving pieces to align. I have pieced together from several question/answers as well as some of the ES documentation the following commands.

My command to build the river:

```
    curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/_river/JDBC_River/_meta" -d @config.json
```

My @config.json doc:

```
    {"type": "jdbc",
     "jdbc": "{
         \"strategy\": \"oneshot\",
         \"url\": \"jdbc:oracle:thin:@server.database:1521/Hello.WORLD\",
         \"user\":\"user\",
         \"password\":\"password\",
         \"sql\":\"select id as \"_id\", count(*) from table group by stuff\",
         \"gridfs\": false
        }",
     "index": "{
        \"index\": \"CHANNEL_DATA\",
        \"type\": \"MDM_data\"
        }"
    }
```

The command I'm using to check that the river exists:

```
    curl -XGET "localhost:9200/JDBC_River/_search?pretty"
```

This command receives this output:

```
    { 
      "error" : "IndexMissingException[[JDBC_River] mising]",
      "status" : 404
    }
```

Moreover, the commands I have pieced together for pulling the data back to view and to delete the river are as follows, respectively:

```
    curl -XGET "localhost:9200/JDBC_River"

    curl -XDELETE "localhost:9200/_river/JDBC_River/"
```

Can anyone help me out as to why my river doesn't exist, but it is created? My hunch is that it is a driver issue and that my river isn't actually hitting the oracle database, but I have no idea what syntax should be used as most of the documentation I've found for Oracle JDBC is outdated.

Comment: What is that "Hello.WORLD" thing in your JDBC URL? The correct format is `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//<host>:<port>/ServiceName `

Comment: Thanks for getting back. That Hello.WORLD thing was just copied from another question/answer forum that I found. I'm not sure what is meant by "ServiceName". What's an example of that?

Comment: Also, is <host>=server.database?

Comment: Host is a network host, specified by either its host name or IP address. Service name is the name assigned to the Oracle instance (=database) by the DBA.

Comment: So, I discussed with my DBA. I have adjusted the host and service name appropriately. However, I still am getting the same error as above. Any other suggestions? Also, I have a question: is my url supposed to be a valid url? if I input the URL into a browser, should it go anywhere?